# 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'is_unique'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

- Operating System: Windows 10
- python: 3.7.11
- IDE: jupyter notebook

I have a dataset with the four following columns: `bug_report_number`, `class_id`, `time_stamp`, `label`. The dataset is something like bellow:

```
41737   120098  1583149803  0
41737   120116  1583149803  0
41737   120136  1583149803  0
41748   120179  1583135020  0
41748   120177  1583135020  -1
41748   120177  1583135020  -1
41754   120177  1583135020  1
41754   120200  1583135020  0
41754   120188  1583135020  0
```

I want to groupby `bug_report_number` and then check if the `class_id` column values are unique for that bug report or not.

For example, for `41748` bug_report_number I expect to get `False`, and for `41754` I expect to get `True`.

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
train_file_path = "dataset_hbase - v.03.csv"
columns_name = ["bug_report_number", "class_id", "time_stamp", "label"]
columns_dtype = {0: "int64", 1: "int64", 2: "int64", 3:"int64"}
df = pd.read_csv(train_file_path, header=None, names=columns_name, dtype=columns_dtype)

temp = df.groupby(["bug_report_number"])
temp["class_id"].is_unique
```

but when I use `.is_unique` it returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'is_unique'
```

Question:

- How to groupby `bug_report_number` and then check if the `class_id` column values are unique for that bug report or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'bug_report_number': [1,2,1,2,1], 'id': [50,35,50,30,50]})
df =  pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby('bug_report_number')['id'].apply(lambda x: 0 if len(list(x))==len(set(x)) else 1)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could use `groupby` + `nunique` + `eq(1)`. The idea is to count the number of unique "class_id"s for each "bug_report_number" and return True if it's equal to 1 False otherwise.

```
s = df.groupby('bug_report_number')['class_id'].nunique()
out =  s.eq(1)
```

Output:

```
bug_report_number
41737    False
41748    False
41754    False
Name: class_id, dtype: bool
```